# how change parameters of url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

**how change parameters of url with htaccess**

I have 2 url like this:

> ```
> 1- example.org/?ptype=writer/5/jon-sina   
> 2- example.org/?ptype=publisher/10/ali-ssadeghi
> ```

I want to redirect that 2 address to these:

> ```
> 1- example.org/?ptype=product/5/jon-sina  
> 2- example.org/?ptype=product/10/ali-ssadeghi
> ```

*

### I wanna just change "writer" and "publisher" to: "product"

*

help me plz :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following directives to your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ptype=(writer|publisher)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?ptype=product%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tanks :)
it solved my problem but i have new problem with this.

this is my url :

 http://localhost/mysite/?ptype=publishers/12/ali-joon

so i have to redirect to this:

 http://localhost/mysite/?ptype=product/12/ali-joon


but htaccess redirect me to this page :

 http://localhost/?ptype=publishers/12/ali-joon

my site is deleted :(